# Accessing iframe contents - code works in the console, but not when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

When I run my code in console it works fine, but when I load the page it gives me an error - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'rowInfo.textContent')

I have two webpages one that is the parent and the other that is the child. They are both on the same local server using the same protocol and port. I have a third file that holds the javascript. Here is the relevant code:

**Parent Page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Broker's Lead List</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://c1eru548.caspio.com/scripts/embed.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="callback"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            autoRefresh_div();
            window.frames['DueDateCounter'].addEventListener("load", alert("loaded"));
            popUpWindow();
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
function autoRefresh_div() {
    $("#callback").empty()
                  .html('<iframe name="DueDateCounter" title="DueDateCounter" ' + 
                             'style="width: 1px; height: 1px" ' + 
                             'src="https://192.168.0.50/CRM/CalanderCountDown.html">Sorry, but// your browser does not support frames.//</iframe>'); 
}

var f, doc, rowInfo, minutesUntilCallBack, calenderItem, calenderItemId;

function popUpWindow() {
    f = $('iframe')[0];

    doc = f.contentDocument? f.contentDocument: f.contentWindow.document;
    rowInfo = doc.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
    minutesUntilCallBack = rowInfo.textContent;

    calendarItem = f.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('td')[1];
    calendarItemId = calendarItem.textContent;

    alert(minutesUntilCallBack);
    alert(calendarItemId);
}
```

After the page has loaded and I go to the console, I can see that the variable `f` is defined, but nothing else is defined. Now if I use the console and put the code in everything works fine. The `minutesUntilCallBack` alerts and so does the correct `calendarItemId`.

I thought it might have been a problem with the `iframe` not being loaded properly, so I put a listening event in, that I have to OK before I run the function `popUpWindow()` that looks into the `iframe`.

I've read lots of posts about similar issues across many sites, but can't seem to get to the correct answer.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `popUpWindow()` function inside of the `onload` event listener for the iframe. It is currently running before the iframe has loaded. `addEventListener` is asynchronous.

```
window.frames['DueDateCounter'].addEventListener("load", function() { popUpWindow(); });
```